# Searching an ArrayList for a String; always return false

Tags: java, search, arraylist

I am having trouble with this method of my class. It always returns false.
Passenger is a separate class. This is a method in my Train class which creates an array list of Passenger objects.  I am making a method that will search the ArrayList passengerList for a Passanger object with the name as the parameter.

```
public boolean search(String a){
    Passenger temp;
    boolean query = false;
    for (int i =0; i<passengerList.size(); i++)
    {
        temp=passengerList.get(i);
        if (temp.getName() == a)
        {
            query = true;
        }
    }
    return query;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 if (temp.getName() == a)
```

should be

```
 if (temp.getName().equals(a))
```

String comparison should always use equals() method instead of == (except that strings literals).

if `temp.getName()` and `a` both not pointing to same object, == condition will fail.

`==` checks for references equality. `equals()` checks for content equality.

This [tutorial](http://tothepointtalks.blogspot.com/2009/05/equals-vs-in-java_06.html) may help you.

Comment: Thanks for helping the link you gave me explained a lot!

Answer (score 2):

`if (temp.getName() == a)` should be `if (temp.getName().equals(a))`.

The former compares references for equality. The latter actually checks to see if the string values are equal.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest writing this code more elegant and cleaner (with checking for null):

```
public boolean search(String a){  
    boolean query = false;
    for (Passenger temp : passengerList)
    {
        if (temp != null && temp.getName()!=null && temp.getName().equals(a))
        {
            query = true;
        }
    }
    return query;
}
```